# Why Google Chrome doesn't set registry entry for extensions in some systems?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, windows-registry, google-chrome-extensions, chromium

I am playing with Google Chrome, Chromium and some other browsers to understand their structure.
I am also using Windows 10.

I want to know what they do to install an extension and how to make it portable. Henceforth, I read an article on how to do this [here](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/pre-installed-extensions). I could install some extensions on my personal Google Chrome using windows registry, but when I want to do it with my friend's system (System B, also windows 10), I found no extension has a key in the registry! Actually, the specified entry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Google\Chrome\Extensions\` in the official doc was empty!. I made it manually but it was not successful!

After all, when I install some extension on System B, the only trace is on `PreferenceMACs\Default\extensions.settings`. I also read a thread in the chromium forum but nothing was found [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-dev/c/0GG6OxQwOCY).

As another chromium-based browser, I found the Edge in my system working the same, with No registry entry for extensions.

So, the main question is, how does the extension install process actually work and how can I force my customized browser to install an extension automatically without asking, i.e. forced pre-installed extensions.

The secondary question is how can I have my personal browser with my favourite extensions and settings without making any conflict with the Google Chrome registry entry? Starting from a compiled simple mini_installer, what should I change with registry settings in the source?

Answer (score 0):

I'm busy with this for days now. I think the only option is to have admin rights and then you can just push the registry keys into `SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallForcelist`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).